# chainerで学習率、lossをplotしたい

Tags: python, python3

今、mnistのデータを使ってNNを実装しました。その際
[ここ](https://qiita.com/sumsum88/items/a62b6950533e8dbb7e02)にあるような学習曲線をPlotしたいですが方法がわかりません
chainerのextensionに[こういったもの](http://chainer%20plot.py)があるようですが使い方がわかりません

また、Adam, AdaGrad, SGDでの学習曲線
BNあり、なしでの学習曲線を比較したいと思っています

+最後に
BNあり、なしの比較時にGradientの値も見たいという状況です

よろしくお願いします！

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from chainer import cuda
from chainer import serializer
import chainer
from chainer import functions as F
from chainer import links as L
from chainer import Variable
import numpy as np
from chainer import optimizers
from chainer import training


train_full, test_full = chainer.datasets.get_mnist()
train = chainer.datasets.SubDataset(train_full, 0, 1000)
test = chainer.datasets.SubDataset(test_full, 0, 1000)


batchsize = 30
train_iter = chainer.iterators.SerialIterator(train, batchsize)
test_iter = chainer.iterators.SerialIterator(test, batchsize,
                                             repeat = False, shuffle = False)


class MultilayerPerceptron(chainer.Chain):

    def __init__(self, n_units, n_out):
        super(MultilayerPerceptron, self).__init__()
        with self.init_scope():
            # full combination
            # at the same time, create a weight matrix (n_inputs, n_units)
            self.l1 = L.Linear(None, n_units)  # n_in -> n_units
            self.l2 = L.Linear(None, n_units)  # n_units -> n_units
            self.l3 = L.Linear(None, n_out)    # n_units -> n_out
            self.bn = L.BatchNormalization(n_units)

    def __call__(self, x):
        h1 = self.l1(x)
        hb1 = F.relu(h1)
        h2 = self.l2(hb1)
        hb2 = F.relu(self.l2(h2))
        y = self.l3(hb2)
        return y


class MultilayerPerceptronV2(MultilayerPerceptron):

    def __call__(self, x):
        # most common activation function
        h1 = self.l1(x)
        b1 = self.bn(h1)
        hb1 = F.relu(b1)
        h2 = self.l2(hb1)
        b2 = self.bn(h2)
        hb2 = F.relu(self.l2(b2))
        y = self.l3(hb2)
        return y


model = L.Classifier(MultilayerPerceptron(784, 10))
# choose optimizer
# AdaDelta, AdaGrad, Adam, MomentumSGD, NesterovAG, RMSprop, RMSpropGraves, SGD, SMORMS3
opt = optimizers.SGD()
# self.setup(Link or Chain)
opt.setup(model)

# device=-1 means Using CPU
updater = training.StandardUpdater(train_iter, opt, device=-1)

epoch = 10
trainer = training.Trainer(updater, (epoch, 'epoch'), out='/tmp/result')
trainer.extend(training.extensions.Evaluator(test_iter, model, device=-1))
trainer.extend(training.extensions.LogReport(trigger=(1, "epoch")))
trainer.extend(training.extensions.PrintReport(
    ['epoch', 'main/loss', 'main/accuracy', 'validation/main/loss', 'validation/main/accuracy', 'elapsed_time']),
    trigger=(1, "epoch"))
trainer.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

短く言えば，[PlotReport](https://docs.chainer.org/en/stable/reference/generated/chainer.training.extensions.PlotReport.html)では，optimizerやモデルを変えておこなった複数の実験の結果を一つの画像に表示することはできません．

もう少し長く言えば，

- optimizerやモデルを変えて，（ディレクトリを変えながら）複数回実験を走らせる
- [実行ディレクトリ]/result/logを読み取って，自分でグラフを描く

ことによって，実現が可能です．

更に長く言えば，ロスの情報は，[LogReport](https://docs.chainer.org/en/stable/reference/generated/chainer.training.extensions.LogReport.html)によって，logファイル(通常では，[実行ディレクトリ]/result/log)にJSON形式でダンプされます．
従って，記録されたロスを適当なJSONパーサ・ライブラリとグラフィック・ライブラリを使って表示することになります．

PlotReportの内部実装では，グラフィック・ライブラリとしてmatplotlibが用いられています．また，Pythonであれば，JSONパーサは，`json`というライブラリが標準ライブラリとして用意されています．

これらの個別のライブラリの使い方については，別トピックを建てて質問することをお薦めします．